# Can anyone tell me why this binary search causes my MacbookPro(Montery v12.1) to freeze?

Tags: python-3.x, search, binary

Sometimes this code finds the correct target, and at other targets- it freezes, I don't know why. Can someone please help? Python 3.9.7. Should return specified target.

```
# the result should return the index
def binarySearch(arr, target):
    left_pointer = 0
    right_pointer = len(arr) - 1
    
    while left_pointer <= right_pointer:
        mid = (left_pointer + right_pointer//2)
        
        if(arr[mid] == target):
            return mid
        if(arr[mid] < target):
            left_pointer = mid + 1
        else:
            right_pointer = mid - 1
    return -1
 
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
target = 5
result = binarySearch(arr, target)
    
if result != -1:
    print(f"the target is at index {result}")
else:
    print("The target is not in the array")
```

Comment: Operator precedence -- division is higher than addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @stark pointed out in the comments, you need to change the way you are evaluating "mid" from "left_pointer" and "right_pointer".

Assume, left_pointer = 7, right_pointer = 9, and your "target" is in index 8 of the array. The way you are calculating "mid", it will be 7 + 9//2 = 7 + 4 = 11, which is incorrect because of the operator precedence. Check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/operators_precedence_example.htm) for better understanding about operator precedence in python.

Working code:

```
# the result should return the index
def binarySearch(arr, target):
    left_pointer = 0
    right_pointer = len(arr) - 1
    
    while left_pointer <= right_pointer:
        mid = (left_pointer + right_pointer)//2
        
        if(arr[mid] == target):
            return mid
        if(arr[mid] < target):
            left_pointer = mid + 1
        else:
            right_pointer = mid - 1
    return -1
 
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
target = 5
result = binarySearch(arr, target)
    
if result != -1:
    print(f"the target is at index {result}")
else:
    print("The target is not in the array")
```